# Visual Studio 2013 tries to load iisexpress.pdb

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, iis-express, pdb

I just upgraded to VS 2013 from VS 2012. The solution opened fine from where it was. However, when I run it, I get an error relating to loading iisexpress.pdb.

If I hit Continue up on the toolbar, it will do so and seemingly run the app without any trouble.  I've tried emptying the symbol cache and reloading, as well as not loading any symbols.  I've also tried using "local IIS" instead of "IIS express", but this requires admin privileges, and even then I couldn't seem to get it actually working (VS just hung and never even opened IE).

Since things seem to work fine when I continue past this error, I'd really just like to know why this is happening and how to stop it.  I'm guessing from the message that it's trying to actually load the debugging symbols for "iisexpress.exe", which of course I don't have.  It never did this in VS 2012 so I'm not sure why it's doing it in VS 2013.

Comment: You don't have source for IIS Express.  Look at the Output window and the Locals window to see why it stopped there; you probably have an exception.

Comment: I realize that, that's why I'm confused as to why VS 2013 is trying to load the PDB file for that.  There are no exceptions, and everything seems to work fine if I continue and ignore this message.  But it pops up every time I run.

Comment: Check the breakpoints window.  What's the callstack?

Comment: The call stack says stuff like this:

iisexpress.exe!012223ee() Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for iisexpress.exe] 

The immediate window has a bunch of lines like this:

First-chance exception at 0x761DC41F in iisexpress.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

Not sure if that was always doing that, or if something changed with the new version of VS that's causing it.  I'm assuming it's a red herring since things seem to work if I go past the error.

Comment: Disable native/mixed debugging in Project Properties (debug tab)

Comment: The only checkbox I saw close to what you said was "native code" under "debuggers" on the "web" tab of the project properties.  This appears to have fixed the issue, although I can't be sure yet if it won't cause some other issue.  Do you have an explanation as to why this was an issue (I'm assuming it wasn't just a guess)?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: You configured VS to attach a native debugger to IIS express.  I'm not sure if it was pausing due to a first-chance exception, a debug hook in IIS express, or something else.

Comment: Not on purpose I didn't. :) I hadn't touched any of those settings myself. Any reason it would have set that differently in VS 2013 by default?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Uncheck Native debugging in Project Properties.

This happened because you told VS to debug native code, and something (I'm not sure what) made it break in IIS Express.

Comment: I hadn't changed that setting (certainly not knowingly), but that definitely seems to have fixed the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it worked for me too however this shouldn't be the best way as complier is showing some error and it should be fixed rather than ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Heck I tried everything, in the end, this worked for me (not saying it will work for anyone else): right click project, properties, untick asp.net. close the page. right click project, properties, tick asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Project properties.Web. uncheck Debuggers Native_Code

Comment: Plese write proper sentences, those unfamiliar with the IDE will not understand what you are saying.